# ionic cordova build Android showing lint warnings

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am getting the following warnings while running "`ionic build android`"

Anyone can help?

`[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/variables.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/Account.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/AccountTemplate.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/BankCodes.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/BillPayments.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/Card.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/Configuration.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/ContactInfo.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/EZcash.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/Ecard.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/ForgotPassword.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/FundsReceived.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/GenarateCVV.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/GetSocialPay.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/ImageUpload.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse200.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse2001.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse2002.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse2003.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse2004.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse2005.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse2006.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse2007.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[12:00:40][Step 2/4] Tried to lint /Users/ibl/BuildAgent/work/57cc7c2dbfdcfaba/src/model/InlineResponse2008.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.`

ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/dev/Documents/IB/PSVB-MBL/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v9.10.1
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS
Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

Environment Variables:

```
`ANDROID_HOME : /Users/dev/Library/Android/sdk`
```

Misc:

```
`backend: pro`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the issue link : https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3735

in your `tslint.json` 
add new rule in `tslint.json`

```
"jsRules": {
    "no-empty": true
}
```